# Sine wave on a ring

Tags: modifiers

I'd like to add a sine wave (like a 3D cut trough this ring) to this ring (along the z-a xis).
I found the math extra objects and a lot of other ways (e.g. curve modifier) to add sine waves, but not how to do this. 
Ideally I could modify the sine wave to other types of waves after that. 
Any help would be great. Thank you !

[image]

Comment: could you please precise what "add a sine wave (like a 3D cut trough this ring)"? Are you trying to engrave your mesh or is it just a bezier question? I'm personally not sure to understand

Comment: Imagine a regular sine wave, but instead of running linear, it runs circular and instead of having no width, it has a width and the space below the sine wave to the ground is filled (at the bottom it is a ring). I assumed I can achieve this by creating the circular sine wave and use it to cut through the ring above. Hope this clarifies what I would like to achieve. Thanks !

Comment: don't you have a picture of what you want?

Comment: If I had a picture I would not need to ask it :) But a bit like this object, but without the gaps to the floor: https://catalog.monroeengineering.com/viewitems/flat-springs/wave-spring-washers

Comment: so I guess you need something non-destructive, like a curve that would allow you to generate a lot of this kind of ring without applying it to the mesh?