# Make sine wave around a circle?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, mathematics

Ok I found this question with no answers - [Sine wave on a ring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129419/sine-wave-on-a-ring) and [How do I make a curve in the shape of a simple wave form (sine)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99865/how-do-i-make-a-curve-in-the-shape-of-a-simple-wave-form-sine) to make a sine curve. I need what the first question asked for -

I now have the sine wave curve, but I need it to go around in a circle. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Glad you fixed it, but.. I've been trying to reproduce this.. and can't! I'm curious about how you managed to lose the axis option?

Comment: old version! of blender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the UI:

**Simple Deform**... modifier.

for any sine wave with a whole number of cycles, created aligned to world axes

- Bend
- 360 degrees
- In the wave's Object-Space axis of amplitude.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Simple script**

Translate the circle primitive into a sine wave.  The primitive circle distributes the verts `x, y` coords in a circle.

The `z` coordinate is adjusted to oscillate in a sine wave.

[image]

```
import bpy
from math import sin, pi
verts = 128 #  verts per circle
radius = 1 # radius of circle
freq = 16   #  how many phases of sin wave
amp = 0.1   # amplitude of wave
# angle per vert
apv = freq * 2 * pi / (verts)

context = bpy.context
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(
        vertices=verts,
        radius=radius)
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
for v in me.vertices:
    v.co.z = amp * sin(v.index * apv)
me.update()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am learning Python by studying examples like yours.